# How to use SQLite with tabview

Tags: android, sqlite, tabview

I have completed the [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) for creating a database and the tabview tutorial from the android developer website.

I now want to combine the two so that each tab pressed opens a different database. I have tried adding the two tutorials together but with no luck.

The main activity class in the notepad tutorial extends `ListView` where the main activity class in the TabView tutorial extends `TabView`. I'm at a loss trying to combine the two.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would basically put the `ListView` *inside* one of the `TabView` tabs.

Starting with [Hello Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), see where it says

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
```

2/3rds of the way to the bottom of the page?   Try replacing `ArtistsActivity.class` with whatever activity you used for your `ListView`.

Comment: Just tried that there and I get a javaRunTime Exception Error. It says my content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list.

Comment: Okay its compiling now. I had forgotten to add the new activity to the manifest. I have done what your recommended above but it just displays the database and no tabs. Any other suggestions? Thankds